# MongoDB find returns documents half the time

Tags: database, mongodb, concurrency, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB with Express and I have a fetch to get a list of users and sort them by the amount of wins they achieved. The problem is that 80% of the time the same code returns a sorted list with no problem, but 20% of the time the response is an empty array [].

I have promises everywhere and I have crosschecked that the problem is in mongoDB's find method, not in the sort method. I know about concurrency and stuff, I just don't understand why this does not work.

```
app.get("/api/account/getSortedRank", (req, res) => {

    const { query } = req;
    const { userId } = query;

    var getFriends = [];

    User.findOne(
      {
        _id: userId
      },
      (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Server error");
        }
        user.friends.forEach(userFound => {
          getFriends.push(userFound.user);
        });

        // getFriends is always correct!

      }
    ).then(() => {
      User.find({
        _id: { $in: getFriends }
      })
        .sort({ wins: -1 })
        .then(sortedUsers => {

          // 50% of the time sortedUsers is an empty array!
          let usersList = [];
          sortedUsers.forEach(user => {
            usersList.push({
              firstName: user.firstName,
              lastName: user.lastName,
              userID: user._id,
              wins: user.wins
            });
          });
          return res.send({
            success: true,
            usersList
          });
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Where does `Friends` come from?

Comment: Friends is an array that contains userIDs, it's always constructed properly and it shouldn't cause any problems. When I get an empty array returned, Friends is not empty.

Comment: The query itself looks fine, so the problem is likely that that `Friends` simply doesn't contain any matching `_id` values.

Comment: But why would it work half the time? This is how I construct friends:

const { query } = req;
    const { userId } = query;

User.findOne(
      {
        _id: userId
      },
      (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Server error");
        }
        user.friends.forEach(userFound => {
          getFriends.push(userFound.user);
        });
        return getFriends
      }
    ).then((getFriends) => {
      
      User.find({
        _id: { $in: getFriends }
      })
        ...

Comment: Done. I think that the problem is that I need to return some values and use 'then( (importedValue) => blahblah...
But again, why would it work half of the time!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing callbacks and promises here, which is likely ending up executing the `findOne` query twice, with different completion times. So `getFriends` is sometimes populated in time, but other times it isn't.

Instead, move the `find` query inside the `findOne` callback:

```
User.findOne(
  {
    _id: userId
  },
  (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Server error");
    }
    var getFriends = [];
    user.friends.forEach(userFound => {
      getFriends.push(userFound.user);
    });

    // getFriends is always correct!
    User.find({
      _id: { $in: getFriends }
    })
      .sort({ wins: -1 })
      .then(sortedUsers => {

        let usersList = [];
        sortedUsers.forEach(user => {
          usersList.push({
            firstName: user.firstName,
            lastName: user.lastName,
            userID: user._id,
            wins: user.wins
          });
        });
        return res.send({
          success: true,
          usersList
        });
      });
  }
);
```

Comment: Big thanks for this one, I though that having a then(() => {}) will only be executed right after the getFriends is populated, however it's executed as soon as the user is found, therefore the getFriends is not always constructed on time.